# How can I remove default styling applied by Svelte?

Tags: css, svelte

I started a new Svelte project and I set the font size of an h1 to 30px. However, in the browser it is displaying as 60px. I investigated a bit and noticed that it is also applying 2em from somewhere else. I checked the inspector and it says it comes from `html.css` but this file doesn't exist in my project.

How can I remove all styles applied by Svelte? I don't want any defaults except for what I create.

Answer (score 0):

Svelte does not have any opinion on your CSS and comes unstyled if you bootstraped it with a default 'skeleton' project (that is, if you followed the standard install procedure).

If you choosed 'Demo app' after initialization via `npm create svelte@latest myapp` however, then there's a `styles.css` in `/src/routes` which you might want to delete.

Anything else is just default userAgent styling, and if you want to get rid of that, you'll need a "CSS reset" stylesheet like [normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css)

Comment: I chose 'skeleton' project. There is still some random CSS applying that I have never seen before. There is no 'styles.css' in '/src/routes'. This style that is applying is only applying to Svelte projects that I create and I have never seen it before. This is not useragent styling because it only applies to Svelte projects.

Comment: Then it's either a caching issue (try a hard refresh) or some extension of your browser (check with another browser) because skeleton  is free of any pre bundles CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I recently created a project choosing 'skeleton' project and also had some pre defined css on it. specially global padding on the body.

I was trying to set height 100vh on my layout and was getting some padding between my layout component and the body component causing the page to have scroll on it.

The solution I went for was to create some sort of reset css.

You can achieve that by adding global rules:

```
:global(body) {     
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}
```